# The order of functions within the integral when finding the area between two curves?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I am trying to find the area between  $x^2 = 8y$ and $x-2y+8=0$ . I know I am supposed to use $\int_{a}^{b} (f(x) - g(x)) \, dx$ to find the area. However how do I determine which one to choose as $f(x)$ and which one as $g(x)$?

Comment: It is almost always useful in problems like this to sketch the functions. Then it should be obvious which function is greater over what intervals, which guides your choices on ordering your integrands (or, equivalently, swapping the limits of integration). You should find a J-shaped cup in your particular problem, with the line at top.

Comment: Thank you. I'm re-learning math after a long gap. Will keep this in mind

Answer (score 3):

You would want the function which has a bigger value to go first. So if there is not one which alwas has a bigger value, you'd split the integral up into small sub-intervals, in all of which, one function is bigger. You can do that by, e.g., looking for zeros of $f(x)-g(x)$, as in all the intervals between those zeros, the functions cannot switch (if they are continous)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by bigger value? The order of the function?

Comment: $f(x)\geq g(x)$. What you basically want to ensure is that the term in your integral is always positive, so your integral doesn't cancel out any area between the two graphs (take $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=-x$ Clearly any integral with bounds at the same distance form zero and a difference between these functinos will always yield zero, although there is a nonzero area between those functions: So what you have to do is take a integral from $a$ to 0 and one from 0 to $b$ (with different orders of the functions in each integral)

Comment: Thank you. Got it